# Validate multiple fields with same name jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have multiple select inputs in my page that are dynamically created with same name.

My code:

```
<select name="area[]" id="area[]" class="area">
    <option value="">Select Area</option>
    <?  
     $cities = $this->city_model->get_all($posters->product_id);
         foreach($cities as $city) { ?>
           <option value="<?=$city->city_id?>"><?=$city->city_name?></option>
        <? } ?>
 </select>
```

I want that user select a value from each select input, I am using jQuery function like this:

```
 $('.area').each(function(){ 
if($(this).val() == "") {
  alert("please select Area");
}  return false;
});

$('.quantity').each(function(){ 
if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == 0) {
  alert("please select Quantity");
  return false;
}
});
$('#form').submit();
```

i did same same with it, it is also working, but it also submits the form as well, even i restrict it at

```
 <input type="submit" name="something" id="something" value="something" onclick="checkType();return false;">
```

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a close brace on your if statement. Try this:

```
$('.area').each(function(){ 
   if($(this).val() === "") {
      alert("please select Area");
      return false;
   }
});
```

EDIT: I re-added the `return false` part, as it is likely the OP only wants to show 1 alert regardless of how many items are invalid.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YLt64/1/)

Comment: `== "" ` is true for `0`, might be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var unSelected = $('select').filter(function(){
        return this.value === "";
    }).length > 0;

    if (unSelected)
        alert('Error!');
});
```

Comment: Or `var unSelected = $('select').filter(function(){
        return !this.value;
    }).length;` ?

Comment: @Johan, `!0` evaluates to **true**, which isn't suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>$('.area').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert("please select Area");
            return false;
        }
    });   
</script>
```